# Ошибка при установке kivy

Tags: python-3.x, macos, установка, kivy, clang

При установке kivy через pip - появляется такая ошибка.

```
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: При установке Си компилятор завершился с ошибкой, что может произойти по многим причинам. Чтобы узнать по какой конкретно причине, нужны дополнительные детали. На каком шаге [инструкции](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-osx.html#using-homebrew-with-pip) произошла ошибка? Приведите полностью команды, которые вы использовали и их вывод. Укажите версии используемого ПО (ось, разрядность, python, clang)

Answer (score 0):

Итак: решение найдено.
ось - macOS High Sierra
всему виной оказалась ошибка описанная здесь https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5468 - решение проблемы внутри.

Comment: в ответы следует помещать .. ответы, а не ссылки на возможные решения. Обновите ответ и своими словами перескажите в чём вы думаете решение здесь ([установить версию из репозитория](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5457#issuecomment-360259285))¶ Обратите внимание [как ошибка была опубликована](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5468) (указан полный traceback, указаны версии ПО), сравните с количеством деталей в вашем вопросе